# data frame with answers, how to keep only the top 100 answers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with answers (the internet color survey). the data frame is like this:

I have a data frame with answers (the internet color survey). the first five rows look like this:

```
id  user r   g   b   colorname
0   1    72  100 175 pastel blue
1   2    204 177 246 faint violet
2   3    182 226 245 baby blue
3   4    130 64  234 purple
4   5    275 49  234 blue
```

with

```
data['colorname'].nunique()
```

and

```
data.colorname.value_counts()
```

I can see that there are 181270 unique answers and their respective count. I would like to remove all the answers that are not in the top 100 from the original data frame but git stuck here.

```
#libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

data = pd.read_csv('color_survey_answers.csv',  delimiter='\t')
data.head()

data['colorname'].nunique()

data.colorname.value_counts()
```

Comment: so only keep the top 100 colors in the dataframe is what you’re saying?

Comment: The idea was to keep for example the rows that have the answer blue because that was one of the most common answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```py
data[data.colorname.isin(data.colorname.value_counts()[:100].index)]
```